# Riemann Explicit Formula

Tags: analytic-number-theory, random-matrices, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

I am writing my senior thesis on Montgomery's pair correlation conjecture, and in his first lemma, he uses the following explicit formula:
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda(n) n^{-s} = -\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) +  \frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s} - \sum_q \frac{x^{q-s}}{q-s} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{-2n-s}}{2n+s}.$$

In particular, the Riemann-von Mangoldt formula is a special case of this where $s=0$. Does anyone know how to prove this? I know this is proven in *Handbuch der Lehre von der Verteilung der Primzahlen*, but I am having trouble reading the German.

Comment: This seems like just the Perron's formula applied to $-\frac{\zeta'(z+s)}{\zeta(z+s)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s\cdot n^z}$

Comment: Indeed: if you read and understand the proof of the Riemann-von Mangoldt formula itself (found, for example, in Montgomery/Vaughan's book), then you should be able to adapt the same proof to this situation (at least for certain values of $s$).

Comment: You should look first at the absolutely convergent inverse Mellin transform plus residue theorem
$$\int_1^x \sum_{n \le y} \Lambda(n) n^{-s}dy = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{-\zeta'}{\zeta}(s+z) \frac{x^{z+1}}{z(z+1)}dz = \sum Res(\frac{-\zeta'}{\zeta}(s+z) \frac{x^{z+1}}{z(z+1)})$$ for $c > 1-\Re(s)$. The convergence is proven with the functional equation and its consequence the density of zeros.